# What makes diffraction spikes move with the focus?

Tags: optics, scattering, diffraction, telescopes

This is a bit of a follow up on [The Bahtinov focusing mask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26301/the-bahtinov-focusing-mask) and it came with [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/38443/what-is-it-about-the-layout-of-the-three-gratings-in-a-bahtinov-mask-that-makes) on Astronomy. But I think the effect can also be observed when looking through a hazy atmosphere or a stained window pane at a distant point light source.

My question is: which physical effect makes a spike move over the light source when adjusting the focus or in other words why does the spike move when the focus changes, while the central point stays still ?

The point is at infinity, usually, while the obstruction is very close. And though the point's Airy disk changes size with focus, the diffraction pattern stays sharp.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking why the spikes change position when we focus the telescope, while the central point stays still?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've changed the wording to clarify.